# Hexagonal Image Transformation With Picasso

Tags: android, transformation, picasso

Hello I am using the picasso image library in my project, right now I am having an issue, I have googled but found no solution.  I would like to give all my shapes a hexagonal shape.

Previous in my previous app I used a circle transformation like this:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(obj.getImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .error(R.drawable.logo)
                .fit()
                .centerInside()
                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                .into(ivLogo);
```

Now I want to do the same but this time with an hexagonal shape, I a having great difficulty with this since I am new to android and do not know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```html
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class HexagonMaskView extends ImageView {
    private Path hexagonPath;
    private Path hexagonBorderPath;
    private Paint mBorderPaint;

    public HexagonMaskView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public HexagonMaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public HexagonMaskView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.hexagonPath = new Path();
        this.hexagonBorderPath = new Path();

        this.mBorderPaint = new Paint();
        this.mBorderPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        this.mBorderPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        this.mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(50f);
        this.mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    public void setRadius(float radius) {
        calculatePath(radius);
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int color) {
        this.mBorderPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
    }

    private void calculatePath(float radius) {
        float halfRadius = radius / 2f;
        float triangleHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3.0) * halfRadius);
        float centerX = getMeasuredWidth() / 2f;
        float centerY = getMeasuredHeight() / 2f;

        this.hexagonPath.reset();
        this.hexagonPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radius);
        this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleHeight, centerY + halfRadius);
        this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleHeight, centerY - halfRadius);
        this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX, centerY - radius);
        this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleHeight, centerY - halfRadius);
        this.hexagonPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleHeight, centerY + halfRadius);
        this.hexagonPath.close();

        float radiusBorder = radius - 5f;
        float halfRadiusBorder = radiusBorder / 2f;
        float triangleBorderHeight = (float) (Math.sqrt(3.0) * halfRadiusBorder);

        this.hexagonBorderPath.reset();
        this.hexagonBorderPath.moveTo(centerX, centerY + radiusBorder);
        this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleBorderHeight, centerY + halfRadiusBorder);
        this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX - triangleBorderHeight, centerY - halfRadiusBorder);
        this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX, centerY - radiusBorder);
        this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleBorderHeight, centerY - halfRadiusBorder);
        this.hexagonBorderPath.lineTo(centerX + triangleBorderHeight, centerY + halfRadiusBorder);
        this.hexagonBorderPath.close();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.drawPath(hexagonBorderPath, mBorderPaint);
        c.clipPath(hexagonPath, Region.Op.INTERSECT);
        c.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        calculatePath(Math.min(width / 2f, height / 2f) - 10f);
    }
}
```

and the xml replace ImageView for

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <com.packagename.HexagonMaskView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally continue with the picasso code....

Comment: In my adapter class do I then use (ImageView) or do I use (HexagonMaskView)?

Comment: My list activity is always empty when I use this, as in nothing displays, I am using an array adapter.  Tried without picasso even and still nothing showed.

Comment: only the HexagonMaskView

Comment: Did you use a custom array adapter for that? May I have a look at your code for displaying the image in the list so I can see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Thank you, works now, It didn't show at first because I was using wrap_content for the width and the height.

Answer (score 0):

after use the BaseAdapter

```css
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import gt.com.greenway.stackoverflow.R;
import gt.com.greenway.stackoverflow.widgets.HexagonMaskView;

/**
 * Created by Pablo on 27/03/2017.
 */
public class AdapterL extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String[] images;
    private String[] titles;

    public AdapterL(String[] images, String[] titles, Context context) {
        this.images = images;
        this.titles = titles;
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);

            HexagonMaskView imageView = (HexagonMaskView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivItemRow);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemRow);

            Picasso.with(context).load(images[position]).into(imageView);
            textView.setText(titles[position]);
        }
        return view;
    }


}
```